# How to remove stop words in Java

Tags: java, string, eclipse

I am trying to find **top k** words in a *"data"* text file. But I cannot remove **stopwords** including in *"stop.txt"* should I do it manually adding stopwords one by one or there is a method to read *stop.txt* file and remove these words in *data.txt* file?

```java
try {
    System.out.println("Enter value of 'k' words:: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    w = new String[n];
    r = new int[n];
    Set<String> stopWords = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    BufferedReader SW = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stop.txt"));
    for(String line; (line = SW.readLine()) != null;)
       stopWords.add(line.trim());
    SW.close();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String text = "";
    String sz = null;
    while((sz=br.readLine())!=null){
        text = text.concat(sz);
    }
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    String[] uniqueLabels;
    int count = 0;

    uniqueLabels = getUniqLabels(words);
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        r[j] = 0;
    }
    for(String l: uniqueLabels)
    {
        if("".equals(l) || null == l)
        {
            break;
        }
        for(String s : words)
        {
            if(l.equals(s))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(count>r[i]){
                r[i] = count;
                w[i] = l;
                break;
            }
        }
        count=0;
    }
    display(n);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("ERR "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post sample contents of files **stop.txt** and **data.txt**

Answer (score 0):

Read file contents by:

```
List<String> stopwords = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("english_stopwords.txt"));
```

Then use this for removing stop words:

```
ArrayList<String> allWords = 
  Stream.of(original.toLowerCase().split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
allWords.removeAll(stopwords);

String result = allWords.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

[Removing Stopwords from a String in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-remove-stopwords)